# Convert "AA" to 0xaa in arduino

Tags: arduino, byte, type-conversion

I need to convert a string like :"AA99BB67" to char[]={0xaa,0x99,0xbb,0x67}.How can I do that?

Comment: Thought about using `strtoul()`?

Comment: How ? it returns long but I need a char or byte value like 0x43.

Comment: Then cast the long to an (unsigned) char.

Answer (score 1):

`strtoul()` will give you a 32-bit value.  You can then use a variety of methods to turn that into an array of characters.  For example, you can use a right shift to move the appropriate byte of the 32-bit value into the low byte and then assign it to an element of your character array.